# How to send array from jQuery and display it in grails controller?

Tags: jquery, ajax, grails

I have a array that contains an array of 10 number in jquery named "winnerList" I am sending it to WinnerController from jquery using ajax as :

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/demoapp/winner/winners",
    type: "POST",
    data: { "winnerList": winnerList },
    success: function(data) {
        alert("Successfully sent winnerList")
    },
});
```

Now I am receiving it inside controller using "winners" function as:

```
def winners(){
    print params
}
```

I am getting result as :

```
[winnerList[0][]:076, winnerList[1][]:118,winnerList[2][]:102, .....winnerList[9][]:18, action:winners, format:null, controller:winner]
```

But I wanted a result of only numbers not this type of structure which i could not access. Can anyone help?

Comment: What is the value of `winnerList` in your JS code?

Comment: i have defined as winnerList=[ ]; and later 10 numbers are stored  in it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got a solution for my own question....
In jquery:

```
............
data: { "winnerList": JSON.stringify(winnerList) },
.......
```

In controller:

```
...............
def listWinnerIds= JSON.parse(params.winnerLists)
..............
```

this will give the values in a list like [1,2,3]

Answer (score 13):

First convert your array to json when send it:

```
...
data: { "winnerList": JSON.stringify(winnerList) },
...
```

Then in the action parse this json:

```
def slurper = new JsonSlurper()
def result = slurper.parseText(params.winnerList)
```

Comment: on doing this I am getting value like this [[112],[12],[114]] its something like list inside list  so how to get only integer without splitting it from brackets ??